# How to convert HTML code of Unicode to Real Unicode Character

Tags: php, unicode

Is there any php function that can convert

```
&#1575;&#1576;&#1576;
```

to it equallent unicode character

```
ت ب ا
```

I have googled a lot, But I think there is no any PHP built in function available for this purpose. Actually, I want to store the user submitted comments (that are in unicode characters) to mysql database. But It is stored in this format `&#1575;&#1576;&#1576;` in mysql database. I am also using `SET NAMES 'utf8'` in mysql query. The Output is in real unicode characters that is fine, but the insertion in mysql is in this format `&#1575;&#1576;&#1576;` that i don't want.
Any Solution??

Comment: For me it looks like somewhere your application is escaping the user input with a function like `htmlspecialchars()` before writing to the database. Is it really stored like this in the database, or is it only presented like this on a page that shows the content of the database?

Comment: @martinstoeckli Actaully, I don't have any problem in storing unicode to mysql database. The Problem is that the unicode characters are converted to the above mentioned html numeric form before insertion to database. I don't know why?

Comment: That's what i meant, a submitted form should send unicode characters, not escaped characters like `&#1575;&#1576;&#1576;`. Do you send the form with `POST`or with `GET`? Is it possible that your code somewhere escapes the input, before it is written to the database, maybe while validating the user input, or maybe you use the wrong escape function to build the SQL?

Answer (score 1):

I googled It and found a very interesing solution [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php#51722)

I have also tried it and I think Its working

```
<?php
    $trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
    foreach($trans_tbl as $k => $v)
    {
        $ttr[$v] = utf8_encode($k);
    }
    $text = '&#1575;&#1576;&#1576';
    $text = strtr($text, $ttr);
    echo $text;
?>
```

for mysql solution you can set the character set as

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
die("error");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you

1 - set your html page's lang encoding to `utf-8` which includes your forms
2 - only use your forms to enter input into your related MySQL db tables
3 - set all collations to `utf8_unicode_ci` in your MySQL (tables and rows collations)
4 - if you have premission you can also setyour MySQL DB collation as  `utf8_unicode_ci`

then you won't see entities in your mySQL records also

This is my solution I use and have no trouble with my mother language which also has lots of unicode characters.

Below I introduce you my db connection php code & recommend (by using prepared statements; please check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

```
//mysql bağlantısı
global $db_baglanti;
$db_baglanti = new mysqli(vt_host, vt_user, vt_password, vt_name);
if ($db_baglanti->connect_errno) 
{
    echo "MySQL bağlantısı kurulamadı: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!$db_baglanti->set_charset("utf8")) 
{
    printf("utf8 karakter setinin yüklenmesinde problem oluştu: %s\n", $db_baglanti->error);
} 
else 
{
    $db_baglanti->set_charset("utf8");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use `mysql_set_charset()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php to set the mysql connection encoding so when you retrieve these from the DB and display them they should be fine.

According to php.net "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."